# how to switch from Sandbox to live in In App purchase

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I am using In App purchase and it is working fine when i am testing it from the sandbox account. But when i tried to purchase the online subscription by making amount zero by live account. it is giving an error of 
[you are not authorised to make purchase in this inApp in SandBox at this time  Environment Sandbox]

i guess it was setup in sand box mode. So As i tested in sandbox and it is working fine ho can i make it live to that any one can purchase it.[image: Error ScreenShot]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got my answer for the apple document that app installed from Xcode is always in Sandbox environment and app download from live itunes is Live. thanks a lot to all and specially for one who commented heae on post and guided me.

=>
StoreKit connects to the sandbox environment when you launch your application from Xcode, from your test device (iOS), or from the Finder (OS X). It connects to a production environment for applications that were downloaded from the App Store. You must not use your test user account to sign into the production environment. This will result in your test user account becoming invalid. Invalid test accounts cannot be used to test In-App Purchase again.
<=
[Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009578-CH1-FREQUENTLY_ASKED_QUESTIONS)

Answer (score 3):

You can not test live app with sandbox test ID as sandbox email ID has no real credit. If In App Purchase is working for sandbox ID, it will work for real IDs too.

Comment: thanks for your response....actually app is live...but i am working on its second version...and creating a build locally and testing it with sandbox account and live account...... but only working for sandbox account....

Comment: and as shown in the image it showing Environment:- sandbox

Comment: For the second version, as long as it is in the not live in the appStore, i.e in the development stage, you can test it through Sandbox ID, and for the version which is in the appStore, it cannot be tested through Sandbox ID

Comment: Not true at all. We just had a case when the app purchase works in sandbox, but does not work in production app